# Using present in the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use the [present package](https://github.com/beardtree/present) in my web app. My web app is using AngularJS. I added the following in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "present":"0.0.6"
}
```

Then, in my controller file, I have the following:

```
$scope.myButton_Click = function() {
  console.log('here 1');
  var startTimestamp = present();
  console.log(startTimestamp);
};
```

When the above code gets ran, I see the following error:

```
here 1
present is not defined
```

I've confirmed that the present.js is being loaded. I don't understand what would cause this.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using browserify?

Comment: Try adding this line to your module definition file var present = require('present');

Comment: Depending how you are loading the present library it could be that present get's instantiated after angular is bootstrapped so it may be undefined at the moment you're calling it. Try using your code in a $timeout with a few seconds delay to see if this is the case.

Comment: @runTarm - I am not using browserify.

Comment: @Ronald91 - Based on the docs, I thought require was only used in the Node.js world for present.

Comment: @CAT - The present library is loaded via a script tag. It is the first library loaded.

Comment: This library doesn't seems to expose anything to public .. Not sure if it should be used in conjunction with anything (e.g. browserify) or not.